# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate and upsert returns no errs, no documents affected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a very minimal model:

```
var CompanySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
});

var Company = mongoose.model('Company', CompanySchema)
```

I am attempting to add a single document if it doesn't exist. Currently, there are no documents while I test:

```
models.Company.findOneAndUpdate({
    name: 'companyName'
}, {upsert: true}, function(err, numberAffected, raw){
    console.log(err, numberAffected, raw)
})
```

This is using the [`upsert` options from the Mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)

However `err` is `null`, `numberAffected` is null. Why isn't my document updated?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

in your code you are using the 3 parameter version of the method `findOneAndUpdate` so, according to the documentation you posted, the parameters are: `A.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, callback)`.

You should use the 4th parameters version of the method to specify the upsert option.

I would like to point out that I never used the framework mongoose. Hope this helps.

Edit:
Yes, in your case, `conditions` and `update` are the same. If your object is more complex then the one showed in the example, you might want to check for the _id or a "unique" (not guaranteed by MongoDB) attribute (better if it has an index on it). For example:

```
var myObj = ...;
collection.findOneAndUpdate({uniqueAttr: myObj.uniqueAttr}, myObj, {upsert: true}, function(){
     ...
});
```

Comment: It's a bit weird: I wish to simply create a document if it doesn't exist, so `conditions` and `update` are the same, but this does fix the prob.

Comment: If you want to create an object then use insert or create.  Update is for finding an object that already exists, and then changing its value.

Answer (score 37):

As of Mongoose 4+, do not forget to set **new: true** along with upsert or you will get the old document as a return value, not the updated one.

This is quite tricky especially when the request creates a document, as if you do not specify new: true, you receive a null document (there was no existing doc), but no error.

```
    var myObj = ...;
    collection.findOneAndUpdate(
    {uniqueAttr: myObj.uniqueAttr},
    myObj,
    {upsert: true, new: true},
    function(...) {...}
```

Comment: You saved my day! Was banging my head after migrating to latest version of mongoose